# Javascript: Input.value does not change in my code

Tags: javascript, object, selectors-api

Usually, you change or get an `input`'s value with: `document.getElementBy eccc.value`

But this strangely does not work in my code.

```js
ret.in = function(where)
{
    if(where === undefined) return false;
    else
    {
        if(isInput(where)) _q(where).value = this;
        else _q(where).innerHTML = this;
    }

    return self;
};
```

Where `ret` comes from a successful `new String()`, `_q()` is a successfull reference to `querySelectorAll()`, `isInput()` is a successful checker for `input` elements and `self` is a reference to the main object the property belongs to (I am building my own library).

I cannot understand why `_q(where).value` does not run in the if statement.
**If I place it just one line above, it works instead.**

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: "If I place it just one line above, it works instead." You mean if you place it outside of the isInput() conditional? If so, then I would guess that the isInput() is not working. Can you provide the isInput() code?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList`s. A `NodeList` has no `value` property.

Comment: @PeteScott isInput() works fine.

Comment: @Robert _q() returns correctly a `HTMLInputElement`

Comment: Does `isInput` really expect a string argument?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal but working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), perhaps as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com), including the related markup and the argument to `ret.in()`? This snippet references too many unknowns (from our perspective) to really be able to help.

Comment: @Robert Uh! You won, ahah... it expected a `HTMLElement` object. It was so simple, thank you